# Rendering EJS template throws an error this.templateText.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to render an EJS template from file but I'm getting an error `this.templateText.replace is not a function`

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const ejs = require('ejs');

const server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
    fs.readFile('index.ejs', function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            res.end("Error");
        }

        res.end(ejs.render(data, { title: "Hello" }));
    });
});

server.listen(4000);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It turns out that `fs.readFile` returns a raw buffer in callback `data` while `ejs.redner` is expecting a string.

> If no encoding is specified, then the raw buffer is returned.

If you want to get a string from `fs.readFile` then you need to pass encoding as a second argument:

```
fs.readFile('index.ejs', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    // now data is a string
});
```

Comment: or use `ejs.renderFile(filename, data);`

Comment: newer node versions use *options* param for encoding. `fs.readFile('index.ejs', {encoding: "utf-8"}, (err, data)=>{ });`